# Run ROS on an Android Smartphone?

Tags: ros, nxt, lego, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

is it possible to run the whole ROS infrastructure on a (modern) android smartphone? Searching the web just yielded tons of pages about android talking to a ROS host..

I've got some LEGO Mindstorms at hand and want to use these with rosjava (and lejos) to develop mobile robotics applications, USB and Bluetooth restrict their range to uselessness.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Andreas

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/32288/run-ros-on-an-android-smartphone?/) by [andreasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/1333/andreasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2012-04-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rosjava](http://rosjava.googlecode.com) runs on Android. Have a look at the [android_core](http://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout?repo=android) repository of the rosjava project.

Please note: rosjava is still unstable and the interfaces are likely to change.

---

Originally posted by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) with karma: 22731 on 2012-04-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [damonkohler](https://answers.ros.org/users/653/damonkohler/) on 2012-04-23**:
Also see the android_core documentation: http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/android_core/html/index.html

**Comment by [LawrieGriffiths](https://answers.ros.org/users/1997/lawriegriffiths/) on 2012-07-27**:
How do you want to use leJOS with Android? How does that overcome problems with USB and Bluetooth? I have recently added new Android projects to leJOS that improve Android connectivity to leJOS,I have not yet tried rosjava on Android with leJOS.